# Is there a complete translation of "Arithmetices principia" by Peano?

Tags: translations, arithmetic

If I understand correctly, *Arithmetices principia: nova methodo exposita* is one of the most important works covering the axiomatisation of arithmetic.
I was surprised that no translation into English (or any other modern language for the matter) was available.

I just found on Github someone who translated part of it but that's it.

Did I miss something?

Comment: According to the Wikipedia entry on his axioms it seems that a work by Jean van Heijenoort  From Frege to Godel: A Source Book in Mathematical Logic, 1879–1931. Harvard University Press. ISBN 9780674324497. which contains a translation of Peano, Giuseppe (1889). Arithmetices principia, nova methodo exposita [The principles of arithmetic, presented by a new method]. An excerpt of the treatise where Peano first presented his axioms, and recursively defined arithmetical operations. Fratres Bocca. pp. 83–97. I have no way of checking that which is why it is a comment not ananswer.

Comment: The van Heijenoort translation does not appear to be complete, finishing at 6 Division. The translation in Kennedy, Selected Works of Giuseppe Peano (University of Toronto Press), is supposed to be complete.

Answer (score 2):

We see one complete English translation of Peano's *Latin* text
[Arithmetices principia: nova methodo](https://archive.org/details/arithmeticespri00peangoog) – which is only 49 pages in its entirety, with just twenty pages numbered in:

> #### VII The principles of arithmetic, presented by a new method (1889)*
>
> This remarkable little booklet (given here in its entirety) contains the first statement of Peano's best-known achievement, the postulates for the natural numbers. The essential ideas were first published by Dedekind, as Peano very generously points out in a later work, but there can be no doubt of the originality of Peano's work, and we have his own statement that he saw Dedekind's work only when *Arithmetices principia* was going to the press.
>
> Following the preface, there is an introductory section on logical notation. In it we find, for the first time, the symbol E to indicate membership and J to indicate inclusion, and a note on the necessity to distinguish these two. The first section of the Arithmetices principia proper contains the famous five postulates, along with four others dealing with the sign =. These postulates were slightly modified in later writings.
>
> The bulk of the work is written in mathematical and logical symbols. The
> preface and explanatory notes are in Latin, and the title is Latin, or almost - 'arithmetices' is transliterated Greek (the completely Latinized form would be 'arithmeticae').
>
> PREFACE
>
> Questions pertaining to the foundations of mathematics, although treated by many these days, still lack a satisfactory solution. The difficulty arises principally from the ambiguity of ordinary language. For this reason it is of the greatest concern to consider attentively the words we use. I resolved to do this, and am presenting in this paper the results of my study with applications to arithmetic. […]

ending with

> 46'. $a \in \text K \text Q . \supset . \text E \text Ea = -(\text Ea \cup \text L \text Ea)$.
>
> — "Selected Works of Giuseppe Peano", Translated and edited, with a biographical sketch and bibliography, by Hubert C. Kennedy, George Allen & Unwin: London, 1973, pp 101–134.

Please forgive the substandard ASCII-like rendering. It matches compared to the last lines in his original booklet:

[image]